# Display a part of web page using iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a dynamic table on a web page and i am calling that page on another application. i am trying to display that table alone and not the whole page. So i wrote a code based on some other answers on stack exchange. But still it shows the whole page. If the table has just 2 rows, then it shows the table with 2 rows and the whole empty page. Not able to figure out whats wrong. Is there any other way ?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function resizeIframe(obj) {
obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.getElementById("dvMain").offsetHeight + 'px';
 // alert(obj.style.height); 
 }
</script>


<iframe src="www.google.com"  width="100%" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"  frameBorder="0" id="iframe" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);'>
</iframe>
```

Comment: If both pages are on the same server you could use XMLHttpRequest to load the text response and 
use the bit from <table to </table> as the innerHTML of a div element. If they are not same origin, you cannot read the contentWindow properties.

Comment: @kennebec :Thanks for the response. can you please show the code outline? The pages will be on same server.

Answer (score 0):

```
function tableFromUrl(url, target, before){
    url is the file path, 
    target is an element to append the table to, if there are two arguments.
    Or, if a third argument is true, insert the table before the target element.
    try{
        var O= new XMLHttpRequest(), txt, 
        div= document.createElement('div');
        O.open('GET', url, true);
        O.onreadystatechange= function(){
            if(O.readyState== 4 && O.status== 200){
                txt= O.responseText;
                div.innerHTML=txt.substring(t.search(/<table/), t.search(/<\/table>/))+'</table>';
                if(before=== true) target.parentNode.insertBefore(div, target);
                else target.appendChild(div);
            }
        }
        O.send(null);
    }
    catch(er){
        //error handler
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response again. I finally got the desired result with the javascript after a slight modification.